# Have a blog...is it evaluated by HR recruiters?

Tags: recruitment, work-experience, blogging

Based upon your experience is it evaluated if a candidate for a job position have a blog?

I mean...if I am looking for a "SQL programmer" (for example) should I give more point to the one who has a blog about SQL and database management or should I only consider the experience in more conventional workplace?
I would positively consider the blog but I don't know what most of recruiters do.

Comment: VTC as a duplicate. The linked question is in fact itself the start of a 4+ question duplicate chain.

Comment: @Lilienthal if you mean that mine is the same question that was asked by the user kce (http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/45057/should-i-start-a-blog-to-help-build-my-online-resume?noredirect=1&lq=1) I don't agree. He is talking about personal blog where speak about himself. I am talking about blog about technical issues and tutorials. Please argue your comment with any link.

Comment: There are any number of linked questions on the one I suggested this was a duplicate of. This topic has been covered many times before. If you believe your question is different you can argue why in an [edit] or on [meta].

Answer (score 2):

As an employer and interviewer, having additional information can help me gain a better view on whether the candidate is suitable for the role. Having a blog, is not very interesting in itself - many people do, and many don't. But if you give a link to specific items on your blog that showcase your expertise or skill, that can be very helpful.

Remember, a blog is useful but not completely reliable - obviously it could be content copied from somewhere else, so an interviewer will not rely on it.

Comment: If you are going to have a blog.  Just be sure it actually puts you in a positive light.  If you publish complete rubbish with spelling and grammatical mistakes, you might lose that job offer, instead of receiving one.  If you copy material from somebody else, expect not to get a job, plagiarism is pretty easy to spot.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to recruitment whether they think the blog is a valuable contribution. The blog by itself is not decisive but a blog along with a github in addition to your work experience and skills - that probably says something about you.

If you are the recruiter, you get to decide how much weight to put on a candidate's work experience, skills set, github and blog - it's your prerogative. There is no rule that says you as a recruiter MUST consider work experience, skills set, github and blog in your decision making. None whatsoever. You can do whatever you want.

My rule is that as a job seeker, your work experience, skills set, github and blog  get you an interview. What gets you the job as a candidate is your performance at the interviews. Critical to your performance at your interviews is the insight that you have gained from your work experience, skills set, github and blog that you are able to share/communicate to those who are interviewing you. They are not hiring your work experience, skills set, github and blog. They are hiring YOU.

No matter how strong your quals are, don't ever walk into those interviews expecting that you're going to get something gift-wrapped and waiting for you to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Blogs can be copied and pasted and Doesn't necessarily show your knowledge in the field.

It's very easy now a days to show off your knowledge via blogs but they does not show your integrity.

For a technical development or programmer job I don't think having a blog matters at all unless your blog is highly followed as that means you have more capabilities as compared to a normal dev.

> And at the end of the day all that matters is your knowledge,which a HR knows how to know if a candidate have it or not(May it be a blogger or not )